# Access VBA find record in code and then set to form

Tags: vba, ms-access

The following code produces this error `runtime error '2455' you entered an expression that has an invalid reference to the property Form/Report.`

The RecordSource behind the subforms is an actual table name.

When debugging, it stops on `Set rs = ...` or the next line.

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Dim rs As Recordset

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM " & Forms!frmTrafficAndLogistics!sfrTnLPO.Form.RecordSource)
    If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then rs.MoveFirst

    rs.FindFirst "PONum = " & Me.PONum

    If Not rs.NoMatch Then
        Forms!frmTrafficAndLogistics!sfrTnLPO.Form.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
    End If

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Use `With` and form properties, recordset or recordsetclone.

Comment: @Fionnuala, why would With matter? It's just a style question, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will only need to assign the Form's recordsource to the Recordset object, like

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Dim rs As Recordset

    Set rs = Forms!frmTrafficAndLogistics!sfrTnLPO.Form.RecordSetClone

    If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then rs.MoveFirst

    rs.FindFirst "PONum = " & Me.PONum

    If Not rs.NoMatch Then
        Forms!frmTrafficAndLogistics!sfrTnLPO.Form.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
    End If

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You forgot `with` from my comment.

Comment: What with are you talking about @Fionnuala?

Comment: `With Me.RecordsetClone`

Comment: You don't need a With in that sample code above.  It works just fine.  The With should be used when running multiple statements using properties and methods from the same object.  that's not the case here

Comment: @david You are running multiple statements. You are working with the form recordset, there is no need to set an rs, just use with.

Comment: @Fionnuala  I see your point....I thought you were talking about the Forms!frmTrafficAndLogistics... object.  I didn't realize you were talking about the rs.

While I understand your intention, I think the With statement makes it less readable in the code and its not my personal preference to write code that way for recordsets.  Also I'm not sure it gives any performance bonus either but that is only my opinion